# Accessing System.Web.Routing.RequestContext from static context in MVC 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to use `System.Web.Routing.RequestContext` in a view model in order to call `HtmlHelper.GenerateLink()`.

In MVC 1.0 it was possible to get the context statically by casting the current `IHttpHandler`:

```
 var context = ((MvcHandler) HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;
```

Now the project has been upgraded to MVC 2.0 and this exception is thrown on the cast:

> Unable to cast object of type 'ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler'.

I'm not sure if it's relevant but this is being run in .NET 4.0 on IIS6.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know what you wanna do with the `System.Web.Routing.RequestContext`? check out:

```
var context = new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(context);

// Use RouteData directly:
var controller = routeData.Values["controller"];

// Or with via your RequestContext:
var requestContext = new RequestContext(context, routeData);
controller = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
```

Comment: Thanks Ben - accepting this one because it directly answers my question but I'd suggest any future readers take note of Darin's answer.

Answer (score 17):

> I need to use System.Web.Routing.RequestContext in a view model in order to call HtmlHelper.GenerateLink().

While in theory you could write:

```
var rc = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext;
```

in practice you should absolutely never be doing something like this in a view model. That's what HTML helpers are supposed to do:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GenerateMyLink<MyViewModel>(this HtmlHelper<MyViewModel> html)
{
    MyViewModel model = html.ViewData.Model;
    RequestContext rc = html.ViewContext.RequestContext;
    //TODO: use your view model and the HttpContext to generate whatever link is needed
    ...
}
```

and in your strongly typed to MyViewModel view simply:

```
<%= Html.GenerateMyLink() %>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin -this is me trying to duck refactoring legacy code :)

Comment: @David Neale, ASP.NET MVC 1.0 is already considered legacy code? LOL. I like it.

Comment: Anything that was written before I start a job is legacy to me! :D

Comment: @David Neale, loooooooooool, excellent. In this case I am afraid that this is not only legacy code but this is bad code, as even in ASP.NET MVC 1.0 view models shouldn't be dependent on a RequestContext.